# BLOB containing binary data retrieved using cx_Oracle returns partial content

Tags: python, oracle, blob, cx-oracle

I am reading a BLOB field in Oracle DB via cx_Oracle in a Python script.
Using Oracle Developers, I get the whole text field.
Using cx_Oracle, the content seems staring from a specific point in the whole string.

Size obtained via dbms_lob.getlength(BLOBMESSAGE) is 8118.
I tried both using a single read or by reading by chunks.

Comment: Would you post your extraction code?

Comment: Fixed...
A special character (coming from blob) was erasing a section of the content when printed out.